# How to find all functions in an R package?

Tags: r, r-faq

What is the best way to find all the functions associated in a package?? I am currently going through the caTools package. If I do `?caTools` or `??caTools` I am simply going to get search for functions called that but not the functions in the package. Is there an easy way to access all the functions in the R gui? Are there any good ways to search for functions?

Comment: no problem, but there was no need to delete the question. I could provide the answer, and it could help others in future who encounter the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am guessing that you are just looking for `help(package = caTools)`, which will open your browser to the relevant help page that lists all the functions in the "caTools" package.

You can also try: `library(help = caTools)`, but that doesn't seem to capture everything. The nice thing about this latter approach is that you can capture the output in case you needed to refer to it somewhere else:

```
x <- library(help = caTools)
x$info[[2]]
#  [1] "LogitBoost              LogitBoost Classification Algorithm"          
#  [2] "base64encode            Convert R vectors to/from the Base64 format"  
#  [3] "caTools-package         Tools: moving window statistics, GIF, Base64,"
#  [4] "                        ROC AUC, etc."                                
#  [5] "colAUC                  Column-wise Area Under ROC Curve (AUC)"       
#  [6] "combs                   All Combinations of k Elements from Vector v" 
#  [7] "predict.LogitBoost      Prediction Based on LogitBoost Classification"
#  [8] "                        Algorithm"                                    
#  [9] "read.ENVI               Read and Write Binary Data in ENVI Format"    
# [10] "read.gif                Read and Write Images in GIF format"          
# [11] "runmad                  Median Absolute Deviation of Moving Windows"  
# [12] "runmean                 Mean of a Moving Window"                      
# [13] "runmin                  Minimum and Maximum of Moving Windows"        
# [14] "runquantile             Quantile of Moving Window"                    
# [15] "runsd                   Standard Deviation of Moving Windows"         
# [16] "sample.split            Split Data into Test and Train Set"           
# [17] "sumexact                Basic Sum Operations without Round-off Errors"
# [18] "trapz                   Trapezoid Rule Numerical Integration"
```

Answer (score 40):

You can get all the objects in your package with:

```
ls("package:caTools")
```

You can get all the function signatures in your package with:

```
lsf.str("package:caTools")
```

Comment: You may have some function names starting wit . , so ls(xxxx, all=TRUE) guarantees that all exported functions are listed. And you can examine source code for functions that are not exported i.e. not really meant for end user but used in a package internally (but that are still sometimes useful - and used - by others).

Comment: Just a comment: the package should be attached before you can list its objects or functions.

Comment: To output just the function names, you can apply as.character to lsf.str

Answer (score 33):

If you want all exported functions (i.e. functions accessible via `::`), then `getNamespaceExports(pkgName)` will do the trick.

If you want all functions in the package, including the ones accessible via `:::`, you can do `ls(getNamespace(pkgName))`.

As an example, with the `stringr` package:

```
getNamespaceExports("stringr")
[1] "fixed"           "ignore.case"     "invert_match"    "perl"            "str_c"               "str_count"       "str_detect"      "str_dup"         "str_extract"    
[10] "str_extract_all" "str_join"        "str_length"      "str_locate"      "str_locate_all"  "str_match"       "str_match_all"   "str_pad"         "str_replace"    
[19] "str_replace_all" "str_split"       "str_split_fixed" "str_sub"         "str_sub<-"       "str_trim"        "str_wrap"        "word"
```

However, we know that `stringr:::is.perl` exists in the package, and as you can see:

```
setdiff(ls(getNamespace("stringr")), getNamespaceExports("stringr"))
[1] "case.ignored"    "check_pattern"   "check_string"    "compact"         "is.fixed"        "is.perl"         "match_to_matrix" "re_call"         "recyclable"     
[10] "re_mapply"
```

So, we see that `ls(getNamespace("stringr"))` contains all of `getNamespaceExports("stringr")` in addition to the `:::` functions.

Comment: I like this answer because it does not require to install an extra package. Only stuff from the base. Cool!

Comment: Note that `ls(..., all.names = T)` may return more names (starting with a dot). Moreover, `getNamespaceExports("stringr")` is not exactly a subset of `ls(getNamespace("stringr"))`, as it also exports `%>%` from magrittr. In general both `setdiff` are interesting.

Comment: This is useful because it doesn't require the user to `library(pkg)` the package they want the exports for. This makes it a good alternative to `ls("package:pkg")`

Answer (score 3):

The `pacman` [package (CRAN)](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pacman) (Dev Version: [GitHub](https://github.com/trinker/pacman)) works well for this.  Specifically the `p_funs` function.

The syntax is:

```
p_funs(caTools)  # exported
p_funs(caTools, TRUE)  # includes non-exported
```

Answer (score 2):

Just figured that if you just go to Environment tab -> click Global Environment -> click the package you want to see (I selected `dplyr` here for demonstration but in your case it will be `caTools`), all functions, values and data will be displayed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `collidr` package

```
library(collidr)
library(dplyr)

collidr::CRANdf %>% 
  filter(package_names  == "caTools")

#    package_names     function_names
# 1        caTools    caTools-package
# 2        caTools       base64encode
# 3        caTools       base64decode
# 4        caTools             colAUC
# 5        caTools              combs
# 6        caTools         LogitBoost
# 7        caTools predict.LogitBoost
# 8        caTools          read.ENVI
# 9        caTools         write.ENVI
# 10       caTools           read.gif
# 11       caTools          write.gif
# 12       caTools             runmad
# 13       caTools            runmean
# 14       caTools             runmin
# 15       caTools             runmax
# 16       caTools        runquantile
# 17       caTools              runsd
# 18       caTools       sample.split
# 19       caTools          sumexact,
# 20       caTools        cumsumexact
# 21       caTools              trapz
```

Comment: Maybe this link should be in the posted answer: ["collidr: Check for Namespace Collisions Across Packages and Functions on CRAN"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collidr/index.html).