# R can't find function

Tags: r, function, fs

I'm a relative novice with R so bear with me.
I have a piece of code that calls the function fs. When I run it, I get this message: Error in fs(x, y) : could not find function "fs"
I know the function is there because I installed it with library(fs).
Can anyone give me some help or advice here?

```
library(fs)
set.seed(33)
n = 50
p = 10
sigma = 1
x = matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p)
beta = c(3,2,rep(0,p-2))
y = x%*%beta + sigma*rnorm(n)
# run forward stepwise, plot results
fsfit = fs(x,y) 
plot(fsfit)
# compute sequential p-values and confidence intervals
# (sigma estimated from full model) 
# out = fsInf(fsfit) 
# out
```

Comment: When did you run `library(fs)`?  Did you run it in your current R session, before you tried to call the `fs()` function?

Comment: Yes, it is the first line of code that I execute.

Comment: Please include your code.  When you type `fs` and press enter, what do you see?

Comment: Delete the above comment, and include that code directly in your question, with four or more spaces on each of code

Comment: When I type fs, I get the same message. It's not found. However, it is in the User Library.

Comment: Tim, code included

Comment: is this a custom library called `fs` as the cran `fs` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/index.html doesn't seem related to your code

Comment: One way or another, the solution will be located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/324364).

Comment: Try `library(help = fs)`, or [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/seeking-functions-in-a-package).

Comment: ... additionally https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/selectiveInference/versions/1.2.4/topics/fs

Comment: User20650, that's the correct function at that link. I think I have the wrong one! How can two functions have the same name and how can I get the one you linked to?

Comment: There are lots of packages that will have the same name for functions as they are developed independently. But the `fs` package doesn't have an `fs` function. So for your code, you will see at the link the relevant package is `selectiveInference` , so you need to install that (`install.packages("selectiveInference")`), and then call library (`library(selectiveInference)`).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Installing the right package was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the package that contains your function by : `help.search("fs")` or `??fs`

Did you installed that package ? If not do it by `install.packages("yourPackage")`

It may also be a namespace problem. So try first of all finding its proper Namespace by `getAnywhere(fs)`

Let me know the result !

Comment: Thanks Youssef. I did exactly that. The package is selectiveInference. Code runs correctly now.

Comment: Add a thumbs up !