# lme can't find functions to set correlation / covariance structure and weights

Tags: r, namespaces, covariance, mixed-models, nlme

I'm currently trying to fit a multivariate mixed model.

I'm trying to include weights and a covariance structure like so:

```
model <- nlme::lme(fixed = ..., data = ...., 
   random = ..., weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Gender))
```

or

```
model <- nlme::lme(fixed = ..., data = ...., random = ..., corr = corAR1())
```

I also tried using `correlation` instead of `corr`.

However, I get error messages:

> Error in corAR1() : could not find function "corAR1"

> Error in varIdent(form = ~1 | Gender) : could not find function "varIdent"

I have tried deleting the global environment and loading everything fresh.
I also reinstalled `nlme` and typed `getAnywhere(corAR1)` and `getAnywhere(varIdent)` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501657/r-cant-find-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you call `library(nlme)` before running? And did you try including `nlme::corAR1()`/`nlme::varIdent()` inside the call itself ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I called it, but I didn't not include ``nlme::corAR1()/nlme::varIdent()`` inside the call.

Comment: you still shouldn't need `nlme::varIdent` in the code if you have previously loaded the package with `library("nlme")` ...