# Seeking Functions in a Package not imported from other packages

Tags: r, package

I want to acquire the list of functions, defined in the package and exported, but not the ones that were imported from other packages?

The following solutions are nice, but list also function re-exported:
[Seeking Functions in a Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/seeking-functions-in-a-package)

Comment: install.packages ("ggplot2", dependencies= "TRUE")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found one more solution that seems to work well:

```
unclass(lsf.str(envir = asNamespace('myPackage')))
```

The benefit is that I don't get these system variables:

```
 "system.file"          "library.dynam.unload" ".__global__"
```

Comment: Nice solution (+1). I will say that I didn't get those system variables with my solution on my machine, but overall I would still prefer your more concise/less involved approach over mine

Answer (score 3):

`getNamespaceExports()` is mentioned in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692264/8386140) to the question you linked; luckily, there is a companion to it, `getNamespaceImports()`. Then we can just find the `setdiff()` between the two. For example:

```
devtools_exports <- getNamespaceExports("devtools")
devtools_imports <- getNamespaceImports("devtools")
devtools_exported_not_imported <- setdiff(devtools_exports, devtools_imports)
"install_github" %in% devtools_exports
# [1] TRUE
"install_github" %in% devtools_exported_not_imported # comes from remotes
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: For me it required also "unlist" for both exports and imports, but otherwise it's a nice solution, thanks!