# Can there be R packages without any functions in it?

Tags: r

I am trying to find the number of functions in each installed R package, specifically package `ggplot2`, `dplyr` , `MASS`, `ISwR`, `babynames`. However, the last two packages mentioned shows 0 as output when I try to run the below code.

I have tried this in R studio

```
NROW(lsf.str("package:MASS"))

NROW(lsf.str("package:ggplot2"))

NROW(lsf.str("package:dplyr"))

NROW(lsf.str("package:ISwR"))

NROW(lsf.str("package:babynames"))
```

I just want to know if a package can exist without any functions in it.

Comment: `babynames` and `ISwR` are "data-only" packages.

Comment: I am afraid your question is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/how-to-find-all-functions-in-an-r-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all functions in an R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/how-to-find-all-functions-in-an-r-package)

Comment: Yes, there is no requirement for a package to contain functions.