# Is there a code to find the number of function in an R installed package like dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

library(help="dplyr") provides me the various functions available in the dplyr package but there is a lot to count. Hence, want to know if there is any code to count these functions available in the package.

Comment: Also this one asked today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848530/can-there-be-r-packages-without-any-functions-in-it

Comment: how about `length(getNamespaceExports('dplyr'))`