# Is R looking for a function that is not there?

Tags: r, package

I'm having a weird issue with R.

Basically, I am following [this](https://osca.bioconductor.org/integrating-datasets.html#setting-up-the-data) analysis pipeline in order to understand how it works. At some point (right after the first introductory paragraph, the last few lines of the history) I find this piece of code:

```
#--- clustering ---#
for (n in names(all.sce)) {
    g <- buildSNNGraph(all.sce[[n]], k=10, use.dimred='PCA')
    clust <- igraph::cluster_walktrap(g)$membership
    colLabels(all.sce[[n]])  <- factor(clust)
}
```

that calls this function **colLabels** which throws a very weird error:

```
Error in colLabels(allEnsembl[[n]]) <- factor(clust) :    cant find the
function "colLabels<-"
```

Now, since I am working with a specific kind of data, i.e. single cell data (bioinformatics here), I've looked into this function and it seems to be part of this package called [SingleCellExperiment](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SingleCellExperiment.html), which I can load successfully before launching the above piece of code.

Once I encountered the error I looked into the R help which can't actually find anything:

```
> help(colLabels)

No documentation for 'colLabels' in specified packages and libraries: you could try '??colLabels'

> ??colLabels

No vignettes or demos or help files found with alias or concept or title matching 'colLabels' using fuzzy matching.
```

Problem is...why does the error point to a function (apparently) called **colLabels<-**?

EDIT: other functions from the mentioned package, i.e. SingleCellExperiment, work and help pages are available.

EDIT 2: I've imported the required library. I also looked into the version I've installed and it seems to be an issue related to the versions. Using `sessionInfo()` R tells me I've version 1.8.0 which fits with what stated in the Bioconductor [website](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SingleCellExperiment.html). The packages version available and also the pdf documentation refers to 1.8.0. **BUT** I've noticed that in the previous [link](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/SingleCellExperiment/man/SingleCellExperiment.pdf) I've attached I was referring to a development version...probably I need to install it (?)

EDIT 3: ok, I have other issues now. The one in the question was an issue related to the package version since the official SingleCellExperiment was 1.8.0 while the doc I found was related to 1.9.3 which was a development version. Once installed, the help for the function works, but the function itself do not.
`sessionInfo()` now states that I have the version 1.9.3 but other functions do not work anymore so, I dont know.

Comment: I don't see what's weird.  It looks like a simple error:  that function is not available.  Maybe it was never exported, maybe it wasn't imported.

Comment: well, to me, the weird thing is that R is looking for a function called `colLabels<-` which is something I've never seen before. Also...I have re-installed the package but still it does not work

Comment: also...what do you mean with: "it was never exported", if I may ask?

Comment: could you check the if `colLables` in the list of available functions in the imported `SingleCellExperiment` package? Use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535247/how-to-find-all-functions-in-an-r-package

Comment: @oszkar it looks like it's not there. But it may be a problem of the package version as mentioned in the EDIT 2

Comment: @gabt a our edit3: have you uninstalled the previous version properly? And I think that is do not related to the original question, so maybe it would be better to ask it in a separate question.

Comment: @oszkar well I'm trying several options and, yes, I believe it was properly uninstalled but still I'm having issues. Let's see if I will come up with something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colLabels function was only added in version 1.9.3. 
This will come out with the next Bioconductor release at the end of this month, see [here](https://www.bioconductor.org/developers/release-schedule/). In the meantime, you can either:

Install R 4.0.0 and start using BioC-devel to get access to 1.9.3, or
Just get and set values from sce$label, which does the same thing.

These are quotes from Aaron Lun's (SingleCellExperiment package developper) [Git Memory](https://www.gitmemory.com/LTLA).

Answer (score 2):

This is the default `R` behaviour.

If you call a not imported or non-existing function, the error message looks like:

```r
> non_existing_function(x)
Error in non_existing_function(x) : 
  could not find function "non_existing_function"
```

If you call a not imported or non-existing function together with an assignment operator, the error message looks like:

```r
> non_existing_function(x) <- y
Error in non_existing_function(x) <- y : 
  could not find function "non_existing_function<-"
```

You have to import the `SingleCellExperiment` package to be able to use `colLabels`:

```r
library(SingleCellExperiment)
```

Update: You definitely have to use the dev version (1.9.3). If you check the [manual for the current stable](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/SingleCellExperiment/man/SingleCellExperiment.pdf) (1.8.0), there is no function `colLables` there, but there is in the [manual for dev version](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/SingleCellExperiment/man/SingleCellExperiment.pdf) (1.9.3).

Comment: I've imported the library. I edited the question to make this point more clear.
Anyway, I didn't know about the "non_existing_function<-" error!

Comment: In R everything is a function. See [section 3.4.4 of the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Subset-assignment) for what the parser does here.